# How to architect an encoder-decoder architecture using ResNets?

Tags: neural-networks, residual-networks

I am trying to implement my own encoder/decoder architecture in Pytorch. Specifically I am trying to use ResNet-18, both for encoding and decoding part. While by following the paper I believe I managed to implement the encoder bit I struggle to understand how the decoder would be implemented.

The understanding I have is that I would need to simply reverse the order of the elementary blocks.
Consider ResNet34 from the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf), whose picture is:

[image]

I assume the last layer (the fully connected one) would represent my latent code. So I assume the first step would be the output of such layer to a sequence of residual blocks converting such latent code into 512 features channels. However because in the encoder the first convolutional module has a stride of 2 does this need to be changed with something else in the decoder part?

Once this change is made I assume I need to pass the output of this sequence to another sequence of residual modules whose conv layer outputs 256 features, where the last one of these I am not sure as well either.

Can you summarize how the decoder would be structured? How is each block inverted exactly?

The reason I've picked res net it's because seems to be fairly common, I did find some code online but I am trying to implement this myself from scratch for sake of practice.

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe tell us first what you need it for? Why do you want to use it? What underlying problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Not particularly sure why that matters. I think the question is fairly complete. As a problem I wanna learn the identity to map an image into another. I don't think it's an XY problem since I have no attempted solutions but just guesses.

Comment: It matters because this question does not have a single "correct" answer. Encoder and decoder are just two networks, they can be whatever as long as they serve the purpose. Sou you could have as well ResNet as encoder and fully-connected network as a decoder.

Comment: Ok, I'll clarify in the question. Though to be honest the title states "ResNet", not sure where the confusion is coming from.

Comment: I understand that you want to use ResNet as an encoder, but still, the decoder can be *anything*, you just need to take some layer of the ResNet as a latent representation and have *some* network decode it back to the data, the decoder does not have to be anything related to ResNet, so the question does not have a single answer. There are many ways how you could define such decoder.